# How to run p4 console command if I use p4v client

Tags: version-control, perforce, p4v

I installed Client p4v from oficial site. I can use only Gui. But I can not use p4 console application. How can I run p4 from console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The P4V installer should have installed the p4 command line tool but if it didn't, you can install the CLI tool itself by downloading from here:
https://www.perforce.com/downloads/helix-command-line-client-p4

Comment: Unfortunately p4v does not contain p4, I had to install p4 from oficial site